# Border-color not working in IE

Tags: jquery, css

I've tried as long as I could to solve this problem before posting but I just can't get it to work.

I have a button for deleting a table row that asks for confirmation before deleting it and highlights the row with a red background/border. In Chrome and Firefox this works as it should but not in IE, the background works but the border-top/bottom don't change color.

When changing the border-color property beforehand it works, so I think the problem is in the jquery css function.

In JSFiddle I created a small example of this problem and in IE it didnt work and in Firefox/Chrome it did, then I saw a topic where they said add the border to the td. I did this and in Chrome the border stopped working on the td, and in IE the border started working on the opposite element of the td.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fere8bj/2/)

```
<table width='100%' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid #DDDED9; border-bottom:1px solid #DDDED9" class='tr'>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>
    <button class='button'>Click</button>
</p>
```

jQuery

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('.tr').css('border-top-color', 'red');
    $('.tr').find('td').css('border-bottom-color', 'red');
});
```

If someone could help me with a working solution in all three browser that would be great.

Comment: You have no style defined for your td border. Look at this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fere8bj/3/).

Comment: why are you using `$('.tr').find('td').css('border-bottom-color', 'red');` when initially you have defined border on `<tr>` only.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal, I've specified that because I found a similar topic where the answer said put the border on the `<td>`

Comment: but for that you need to assign complete border to `<td>` if you just change the border color it will not work

Comment: @Huelfe Thanks! That did the trick, now it works in all browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define border first, then add border color.

```
td {
   border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}
```

OR 
Add in Jquery `'border-bottom', '1px solid red'`

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('.tr').css('border-top-color', 'red');
    $('.tr').find('td').css('border-bottom', '1px solid red');
});
```

why don't you just change the border color of tr **for exampe**

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('.tr').css('border-color', 'red');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fere8bj/5/)

Comment: Second example works, the problem was that the third was my initial solution but this didn't work in IE.

Comment: So you want another solution or go with this ?

Answer (score 0):

When I use Chrome the bottom border color does not change. This code works:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  $('.tr').css('border-top-color', 'red');
  $('.tr').css('border-bottom-color', 'red');
  $('.tr').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```